# How do I know if UITableViewCell is selected?

Tags: uitableview, uidatepicker

I would like to imitate a behavior like the one that is in the apple calendar when selecting a date for an event. You have a TableView with to cells and a datepicker. If the first cell is selected the date of the picker is for start date and the opposite  for end date.

So, my question is: how do I Know, when handling the date change in the DatePicker, what cell is being selected in tableview at that moment?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( 0 == [[yourTable indexPathForSelectedRow] compare:[yourTable indexPathForCell:yourCell]] ) {
  // yourCell is selected
}
```

or you might be able to tell just by looking at indexPathForSelectedRow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

and check indexPath.row